# Import All Function present in directory Dynamically into a script

Tags: linux, function, import, sh

Folder where All custom Functions will be Kept :-**home/Function/Lib/**

Script that loads all the functions :- **home/Function/Function_Load.sh**

taking example of above locations , I want to create a structure in which 
/Function_Load.sh will load all the function present in home**/Function/Lib/**
i.e. in cases when I add new functions in home/Function/Lib/ ,no changes should be made in home/Function/Function_Load.sh

The main idea is , for all new scripts that would be created ,will call Function_Load.sh to load all the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both Bash and Sh that should do the trick.

```
for f in Function/Lib/*.sh; do source $f; done
```